# How to edit and save contents of a single column of an already existing row in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have an app for registration

My registration model:

models.py
1. name
2. address
3. registration_status (default value = no)

forms.py
1. name
2. address

I am not including registration_status in my forms.py because the user is not allowed to edit it, it is reserved for admin access.

On my admin page, I have successfully been able to display the users' names and addresses entered by them with the default value of no for registration_status. This registration_status column is a drop down with options yes, no and pending.

I am facing a problem with saving this drop down value selected by the admin as this value needs to correspond to the right user's name and address that already exists in the database.

Tried the following:
1. Split the form into 2 and tried - unsuccessful
2. Used only HTML for the dropdown - save unsuccessful

Have any of you tried this before?

Comment: Why don't you add the drop down field to the form that is shown to the admin?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - as of now, the page shown to the admin is not a form (it is only a drop down with options) as we are unable to add two forms; is there a way of having 2 forms?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should re-read the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/). It will help you with the basics.

Anyways, the solution you are looking for:

```
user = YourModel.objects.get(pk=1)  # get the object
user.registration_status = True  # change the object
user.save()  # save the object
```

Comment: If pk=1 is referring to user1, then how are we saving the selected option (from the dropdown) to user1?

Comment: The selected option is in a form. So if you `POST` this form to your view, you may access the data and change the user. All described in the tutorial.